# Looping on R with data extratcted from web site

Tags: r, loops, rvest

I need to scrap some data from a website that changes only by a number.
I tried to make a loop but I just can't do it. This is the way with I've tried. I'm using the library `rvest`

```
prueba <- data.frame(1:11)

for(KST in 861:1804)){
  url <- print(paste("https://estudiosdemograficosyurbanos.colmex.mx/index.php/edu/rt/metadata/",KST,"/0", sep="")) ## from 861 to 1804
  webpage <- read_html(url)
  articles_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, 'tr:nth-child(4), tr:nth-child(6), tr:nth-child(8), tr:nth-child(10)
                            , tr:nth-child(12), tr:nth-child(20), tr:nth-child(22) , tr:nth-child(28)
                                   , tr:nth-child(26), tr:nth-child(30), tr:nth-child(32)')
  articles_data <- html_text(articles_data_html)
  #putting on a dataframe
  as.data.frame(prueba[paste("a",KST,sep="")])<-articles_data
  }
```

somebody can help me about how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) `as.data.frame(1:11)` should be `data.frame(a = 1:11)`. 2) In `c(861:1804)` you don't need `c()` 3) From `861` to `1804` it's `45` but the df only has `11` rows. 4) What is `rank_data`, it's not defined, do you mean `articles_data`?

Comment: 5) Finally, try `paste0('https://estudiosdemograficosyurbanos.colmex.mx/index.php/edu/rt/metadata/', KST, '/0')`.

Comment: prueba <- data.frame(1:11)
for(KST in c(861:1804)){
  url <- print(paste("https://estudiosdemograficosyurbanos.colmex.mx/index.php/edu/rt/metadata/",KST,"/0", sep="")) ## from 861 to 1804
  webpage <- read_html(url)

Comment: I've been solved that part. But now i can't write the data in the dataframe...

Comment: `rank_data` **does not exist**, it was not created. What you have read is `articles_data`. And edit **the question** with the new code, do not post code in comments, please.

Comment: Now i have this error: [`Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, paste("a", KST, sep = ""), value = c("Gustavo Garza Villarreal",  : 
  replacement has 7 rows, data has 11`]

Comment: Sorry. Im not used to this plattform

Comment: I am getting this error: *Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)*.

Comment: Maybe for the Country in which you are. :( But hthanks. With the info in your first comment and looking what to do in basic treatment o dataframes i've achived my purpose. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use a dataframe, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the best way to solve your problem is to use an object of class `"list"` to hold what you are reading in. Something like the following.

```
library(rvest)

prueba <- vector("list", length(861:1804))

for(KST in 861:1804){
    url <- paste("https://estudiosdemograficosyurbanos.colmex.mx/index.php/edu/rt/metadata/",KST,"/0", sep="") ## from 861 to 1804
    webpage <- read_html(url)
    articles_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, 'tr:nth-child(4), tr:nth-child(6), tr:nth-child(8), tr:nth-child(10)
                            , tr:nth-child(12), tr:nth-child(20), tr:nth-child(22) , tr:nth-child(28)
                                   , tr:nth-child(26), tr:nth-child(30), tr:nth-child(32)')
    articles_data <- html_text(articles_data_html)
    #putting on a dataframe
    prueba[[KST]] <- articles_data
}
```

Then, when you are done, maybe end with

```
closeAllConnections()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm checking how to use the data on the list. But your code solved the problem of columns disparity on information.